# Is there a python design pattern for a Grid class that can contain different types of Cell classes?

Tags: python, design-patterns

For a python hobby-project I needed a grid that consists of cells, as in:

[image: Grid consisting of cells]

For this I created a generic Grid class that contains a list of generic Cell objects. Both have sub-classes, because I need different types of grids, each of which contain different types of cells. Like in this class diagram:

[image: Class diagram]

I implemented the generic Grid and Cell classes as follows:

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, row_index, column_index):
        self.row_index = row_index
        self.column_index = column_index

class Grid:
    def __init__(self, size, cell):
       self.cells = [cell(i, j) for i in range(size) for j in range(size)]
```

In which the `cell` parameter of the `Grid` constructor specifies which type of cell to use for building up this grid. A specific sub-class would then look as follows:

```
class CellS(Cell):
    def __init__(self, row_index, column_index):
        super().__init__(row_index, column_index)
        # other stuff

class GridA(Grid):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(9, CellS)
```

It works fine, but it feels a bit weird (and it has the downside that the constructor of the Cell sub-classes cannot have additional parameters, but that is not an issue for my case).

Am I overlooking some obvious design pattern for handling such a situation? I did a bit of research, but I could not find any suitable other solution for this.

Comment: Why can't the subclasses have additional arguments?

Comment: Because the cell subclass constructer is called in the general Grid constructor (cell(i, j)), so it can only have these two parameters.

Comment: Python function arguments are very dynamic, you can use optional arguments with defaults and even catch all positional and keyword arguments with `def f(*args, **kwargs)`.